# How to write regex for empty string and non empty string in one in cucumber

Tags: java, regex, selenium, cucumber

I have a feature and step definition file in which i have empty values coming through data table.But for empty string the regex is getting failed

Feature File : - 
1) @SPRegression @done1
  Scenario Outline: Verify user is unable to login with valid email and invalid length password.

```
Given User is on login screen

When User performs login with existing user account that has players in the account with <username> and <password>

Then Verify user is unable to login, an incorrect credentails popup for invalid password length is displayed

Examples: 
  | username                           | password|
  | testing+automation@squarepanda.com | invalid |
```

2)  @SPRegression @done
  Scenario Outline: Verify user is unable to login with valid email and empty password.-C3236

```
Given User is on login screen

When User performs login with existing user account that has players in the account with <username> and "<password>"

Then Verify user is unable to login, an incorrect credentails popup for empty password is displayed

Examples: 
  | username                           | password |
  | testing+automation@squarepanda.com |          |
```

Step deifinition file : -

```
@When("^User performs login with existing user account that has players in the account with (.+) and (.+)$")
    public void user_performs_login_with_existing_user_user_account_that_has_players_in_the_account(String username,String password) throws Throwable {
        try {           
                loginScreenCoreLogic.performLogin(username, password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ErrorReporter.reportError(e);
        }
    }
```

Scenario 1 gets passed but 2 gets failed due to regex, i tried google, but didn't got any solution.

I need a regex which handles both empty and non empty string in one method as shown in Step definition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your question, so it becomes readable.

Comment: Maybe out of scope, but why specifically invalid length password?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a wilcard instead of a quantitive match

```
@When("^User performs login with existing user account that has players in the account with (.+) and \"(.*)\"$")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cucumber datatable](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/datatable).

Scenarios:

```
Given User is on login screen
When User performs login with existing user account that has players in the account with:
  | username | testing+automation@squarepanda.com  |
  | password | password                            |
```

```
Given User is on login screen
When User performs login with existing user account that has players in the account with:
  | username | testing+automation@squarepanda.com  |
  | password |                                     |
```

Step definition file:

```
@When("^User performs login with existing user account that has players in the account with:$")
public void user_performs_login_with_existing_user_user_account_that_has_players_in_the_account(Map<String, String> params) throws Throwable {
    try {           
        loginScreenCoreLogic.performLogin(params.get("username"), params.get("password"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ErrorReporter.reportError(e);
    }
}
```

Datatable supports `examples`:

```
When User performs login with existing user account that has players in the account with:
  | username | <username>   |
  | password | "<password>" | 

Examples: 
  | username                           | password |
  | testing+automation@squarepanda.com |          |
```